# KeyboardEventArgs attributes Code is "" and Key is "Undefined" on mobile Android

Tags: android, .net, blazor, maui

I tried to use Mudblazor MudTextField's OnKeyDown . But KeyboardEventArgs gives undefined argument when i press a button. But i want to trigger a function when enter button pressed in the soft keyboard. Is there any other solutions for this issue. I have seen this issue reported in github

[githublink](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16030)

I'm desperate for an answer. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [native android official document about the KeyBoard event](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/keyboard-input/commands) said:

> Note: When handling keyboard events with the KeyEvent class and related APIs, expect that the keyboard events are coming only from a hardware keyboard. Never rely on receiving key events for any key on a soft input method (an on-screen keyboard).

So you can't get the key code from the soft keyboard event. This is android native limit.

**Update:**

I have tested again. The soft keyboard's enter pressed event will trigger twice and the second time will get the `e.Key : Enter` and `e.Code :` . You can check it.

Comment: Did you know about android? Did you try the JS workaround you mention on the android soft keyboard? I have tested all the api about android key event I know to detect the key pressed event from the soft keyboard. @T.Trassoudaine

Comment: I realized that you are only talking about software Apps on Android. My solution is running on a browser.

Comment: They are the same. I am trying with a JS function now. @T.Trassoudaine

Comment: Well I am binding a keyup event handler with jQuery and checking for `event.which == 13`.

Comment: I have tried, it didn't work. @T.Trassoudaine